# Is there a way to allow SSH from specific machines on Centos?

Tags: ssh, centos, centos7

I need to restrict SSH on a Centos7 server and limit it to one workstation per user. I cannot use IP address, since it is assigned dynamically by VPN and can be different in each session. Bottom line is, each user should only be able to access the server from one workstation at a time. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by editing the limits.conf file - /etc/security/limits.conf

Add

username  -  maxlogins 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use public key Authentication, this is the links:
https://kb.iu.edu/d/aews

https://www.linode.com/docs/security/authentication/use-public-key-authentication-with-ssh/

https://www.u.tsukuba.ac.jp/en-publickey/

Comment: Thanks Muhammad. I believe your solution limits login from one "specific" device (where the key is stored) to server, if I am not wrong. But I needed to limit the login to one session, no matter what device is being used.